# How to select post ID for given parent name with nested prepared queries?

Tags: php, wp-query

I've just started development for the wordpress environment. I am trying to create a prepared statement for the nested query which selects post ID (ID) for the specified parent name (post_parent)? Is it at all possible, because I couldn't find too much on the nested queries in wp, never mind using prepare for it.

This is the SQL I wrote to achieve it.

```sql
SELECT ID from wp_posts WHERE post_parent=(SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title="Phase 1" AND post_name="phase-1") AND post_title !="Phase 1"
```

Can I at all write one prepared statement for it or do I have to first get an array of child pages and then run another query in a loop?

Comment: WP developers rarely write nested SQL statements, and it's generally seen as bad practice to write raw SQL queries in WP. Instead make use of the API functions and objects such as `WP_Query` etc for querying posts etc

Comment: Thank you for your answer and pointing me into the right direction. I will look into wp_query class